# UNION a table from multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a `MS SQL 2005 (9.0.5000) Server` that has multiple databases which are named `Mailing_XXXX` where `XXXX` is a sequential number. I need to combine multiple tables from different `Mailing_XXXX` databases. The problem is that I can only determine which `XXXX` I want to use by running another `SQL statement`.

So if I run this `T-SQL` statement:

```
SELECT
    DatabaseName
FROM
    Config.dbo.Template
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%Mailing_%'
```

It will return:

```
DatabaseName
Mailing_2491
Mailing_2663
Mailing_2664
Mailing_2666
Mailing_2667
Mailing_2670
```

So I need to create a combined table that contains the `PrimaryAddress` table of each of those Mailing_ databases.

If I were to write this code manually I can easily do:

```
SELECT * FROM Mailing_2491.dbo.PrimaryAddress
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Mailing_2663.dbo.PrimaryAddress
UNION ALL
   (etc etc)
```

However, I need this to run on a daily basis because new mailings will constantly be getting added and deleted. So my main challenge is dealing with the variable `Mailing_` numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DatabaseName)
FROM Config.dbo.Template
WHERE Name LIKE '%BLAH%'

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, LEN(' UNION ALL'), '')
PRINT @sql;

EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: Should be `EXEC (@SQL)` or better still `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL` as it can be parameterised if necessary. Just `EXEC @SQL` will throw an error `Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM Mailing...'`

Comment: Also, why `LEN(' UNION ALL')` instead of, well, `10`? Just to make the code longer and more complex?

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the databases and execute the statement based on your example:

```
CREATE TABLE #dbs (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), dbname VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #dbs
        ( dbname )
SELECT
    DatabaseName
FROM
    Config.dbo.Template
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%BLAH%'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @dbcount INT

SELECT @dbcount = MAX(id) FROM #dbs

WHILE @i <= @dbcount
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + dbname + ' UNION ALL'
    END

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 10) --get rid of trailing union all
DROP TABLE #dbs

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note** It would make more sense from a relational database perspective to have one database with all the mailing info, and a separate table to differentiate the "mailing numbers".

Comment: ...or a column for MailingID

Comment: Yup, column would make the most sense